# How to automount an Android phone as USB mass storage?

Tags: usb, mount, android

When connecting my Android device to a PC, it prompts to mount it as USB mass
storage.

Is there a way to force it to auto-mount?

Comment: Which OS is the host? By your question I assume linux.

Comment: From the question this could be any desktop OS. When you attach an Android phone to a PC, the *phone* gives you the option to mount itself as a USB mass storage device on the PC.

I think the questioner is asking if you can stop the phone asking and set it to just always mount when attached.

Comment: Which do you mean?  "When connecting the Android device to the PC, the PC prompts to mount it"?  Or "When connecting the Android device to the PC, Android prompts to mount it"?

Comment: I believe this question should be moved to Android Enthusiasts. Also, I think recent versions of Android offer this option natively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the answers on here were correct at the time, since then a few apps have come along that solve the auto-mounting problem:

**[AutoMount](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jrtstudio.automount&feature=search_result)**

[image]

**[MountUSB](https://market.android.com/details?id=at.abraxas.mountusb.donate&feature=search_result)**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This would have to be solved by an application on the phone, to my knowledge, one does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

> [Automatically Mount Your Android Storage via USB](http://lifehacker.com/5584889/install-doubletwist-player-for-automatic-android-usb-mounting)

Free and great app for doing this: [DoubleTwist Player](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.doubleTwist.androidPlayer&feature=search_result).

Answer (score 1):

The [Winamp app for Android](http://www.winamp.com/android) also has an "Auto-Mount" option.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to dual mount an SD card on a Cliq YMMV:

```
echo /dev/block/mmcblk0 > /sys/devices/platform/usb_mass_storage/lun0/file
```